# Can't connect to Cosmos DB emulator Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, jestjs, github-actions

On Github Actions I have a Cosmos DB emulator started with a Docker Compose command and some tests with Jest (it's a Node.js project) trying to reach the Cosmos DB instance.

Here's the Docker Compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  cosmosdb:
    restart: always
    container_name: "azure-cosmosdb-emulator"
    hostname: "azure.cosmosdb"
    image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest'
    tty: true
    ports:
    - '8081:8081'
    - '10250-10255:10250-10255'
    environment:
      AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT: 10
      AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE: "true"
```

Here's the GitHub Actions:

```
jobs:
  run-tests:
    timeout-minutes: 10
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2

      - name: Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node
            
      - name: Docker Compose
        run: |
          docker compose -f tests/docker-compose.yml up -d

      - name: Integration test
        run: |
          cd tests
          yarn install --immutable
          yarn test
          cd ..

      - name: Docker Compose
        run: docker compose -f tests/docker-compose.yml down
```

Now, the Cosmos DB instance is exposed on port 8081. If I add some debugging steps to the GitHub Actions like `docker ps -a` to see all the running containers and `nc -zv localhost:8081` I have these results:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                                                              NAMES                                      
b8b1b1e58646   mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest   "/usr/local/bin/cosm…"   32 seconds ago   Up 23 seconds   0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp, :::8081->8081/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10250-10255->10250-10255/tcp, :::10250-10255->10250-10255/tcp   azure-cosmosdb-emulator
```

```
Connection to 0.0.0.0 8081 port [tcp/tproxy] succeeded!
Connection to localhost (::1) 8081 port [tcp/tproxy] succeeded!
```

But when the tests are executed they can't connect succesfully to the Cosmos DB instance at https://localhost:8081 (timeout error). I've tried the tests on my local machine and it works.

Here are the logs from the Docker container.

```
This is an evaluation version.  There are [115] days left in the evaluation period.

Shutting Down

Shut Down

This is an evaluation version.  There are [115] days left in the evaluation period.
Shutting Down

Shut Down

This is an evaluation version.  There are [115] days left in the evaluation period.
Starting

Connection to 0.0.0.0 8081 port [tcp/tproxy] succeeded!
```

Even if the Docker container is up, the emulator seems to stuck on start. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems to be a known issue of the emulator -> 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-db-emulator-docker/issues/64.
Has anyone solved the problem ?